# Option to share a file uploaded privately with a Community User

Tags: community, sharing, files

When i upload a file under Files Tab we have share option. But we can only share with internal users...but not with partner users. I was wondering if its possible to share file with a partner community user.

[image]

There is option to share file in library and add partner users as members to that library...but this solution is not feasible if we want to share privately with large number of users.

Also the Files sharing option has Public link option but that also is not the ideal solution.

Comment: Is there a property you can use to automatically identify a partner user as someone who should be able to see the file?  Sounds like it isn't all partner users, but quite a lot.  How can we tell which ones?

Comment: Are you looking to share a File in general or a File uploaded to a record with Partner Users?

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld i was thinking using just their Name we can identify which user to share file with. eg. lets say i have a partner user XYZ in community and i am salesforce licensed user, want to share file either from salesforce or from community. While sharing i would just select the name of user to share file with that community user........ but i have been searching for hours and haven't found any working solution that can simply share a file with a Partner community user privately.

Comment: @JayantDas I am looking to share file in general but i am open to other options as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do this.

If at all you have say a Record that the Community User has access to, you can attach the File to that particular record and that way they get access to the File. You will need to write a trigger for this. The trigger should be on the `ContentDocumentLink` and it will be as below:

```
for(ContentDocumentLink cont : Trigger.new){ 
    cont.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
}
```

Though the visibility is set to all users, but only those users will be able to view the Files associated to a Record, to which they have access to.

For more details, refer to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271156&language=en_US&type=1).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **private** chatter group and add those partner members to that chatter group and upload the file into the chatter group.

This is effective way to share files. Think about that, how through the use of partner portal, we as partners get access to the file.

**Update**

It can only be possible through `Share via Link`, since that file is not attached to a record that community user has access to.

So, you can either send via email or post the link to the chatter which community user can access.

Comment: yes that might work but lets say i want to send 10 different community users their unique files...i.e. 1 file will go to 1st community user and 2nd file to 2nd community user and so on. for this i will need to create 10 chatter groups and add one user in their groups and share file with correct groups.

Comment: What i am trying to do is simple. Just share a file with a community user that other community user cant see.

Comment: refer my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @SantanuBoral for highlighting the private type of a chatter group. It helped me to fix an issue of additional access to partner users. Thanks a ton. It saved my life.